# How to set the default jupyter notebook editor in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have the [Jupyter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter) installed<sup>1</sup> in Visual Studio Code. Whenever I click on a Jupyter Notebook (.ipynb), VS Code opens the "old" editor and shows me a deprecation message.

I can manually select the new built-in editor by right-clicking the file and selecting *Open with...* and then "Jupyter Notebook built-in".

**How can I set Visual Studio Code to use the new built-in notebook editor by default?**

---

<sup>1</sup> I need it installed, to be able to create new Jupyter Notebooks. I did not find a way to do this with the built-in editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Right-click on the .ipynb file in the explorer window (in the directory file list, not under "Open Editors").
2. Pick "Open With"
3. Pick "configure default editor" at the bottom of the list
4. Pick "Jupyter Notebook"

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that, unless this feature was recently introduced.

Comment: I don't see the "configure default editor" option on the right click list.